# I am trying to get tokens from a file and make a linked list. But I am failing at it

Tags: c

I am trying to open using sys call and read in tokens from the file. I need to create a linked list of tokens. I am getting tokens but once I tried my little implementation of trying to create nodes. I am getting a Segmentation fault: 11  What am I doing wrong here ?

I have been on with this for a long time and I can not seem to get this down. Any help will be helpful. Thank you

I want to know if my implementation is even correct for reading in tokens from the file and making a linked list?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1000

struct node {
    char data;
    struct node *next;
};

int
main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    // char str[100] = "Hello, my, name, is, Amir";
    const char s[2] = ",";
    char *token;


    // printf("\nREAD FROM STRING.\n");
    // //get the first token
    // token = strtok(str, s);
    // printf("First token: %s\n", token);

    // while(token != NULL)
    // {
    //  printf("%s\n", token);

    //  token = strtok(NULL, s);
    // }
    printf("file name: %s\n",argv[1]);
    int fd, flag;
    char *buffer[BUFSIZE];

    char *print_tokens;
    int token_idx;

    char read_char;

    struct node *p, *q, *head;
    int i, n, item;

    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if(fd == -1)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    // create the first node 
    q = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    q->data = item;
    q->next = NULL; 

    printf("\nREAD FROM FILE.\n");

    while((flag = read(fd, &read_char, 1))> 0)
    {

        token = strtok(&read_char, s);  

        // create a node and point the value to the node
        q = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        q->data = token;
        q->next = NULL;


        p->next = q;
        p = p->next;
        // while(token != NULL)
        // {
        //  printf("%s\n", token);

        //  token = strtok(NULL, s);

        // }

    }

    p = head;
    while(!p)
    {
        printf("%s\n", p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }

    return 0;
}

//comparator function for strings
int compare(char *str1, char *str2) {
  while (*str1 && *str1 == *str2) {
    str1++;
    str2++;
  }
  return *str1 - *str2;
}
```

Comment: You’re at least trying to read 1000 bytes into a single byte which may cause issues... Did you run the code in a debugger line by line to determine where it crashes?

Comment: Yes I tried different numeric values. This is my first c project and this is just one part of the project. I am trying my best where as we only got very little resources. I wish we could have gotten more stuff to understand but I am trying and all is failing  so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field `data` of the structure `node` is of type `char` and you assign `item` to it which is of type `int` and is not initialized when you create the first node. This can’t work and shouldn’t even compile.

You are then reading a single `char` from the file and executing `strtok` on it. A `char` is not a string. It thus have no ending '\0'. This can’t work.

You should read a full line and execute `strtok` on the line. Use the function `getline` instead.

Token is a string, thus a `*char` and you assign it to `data` which is of type `char`. This can’t compile because the compiler should report an error.

If you want to store strings in the linked list, the `data` field should be of the type `*char`. When you assign a value to the `data` field, you should copy the string into an allocated block.

Here is an example implementation. I don’t know the purpose of the `compare` function. Do you have to sort the list of tokens ?

**UPDATE** The code has been updated to use `read` and `open` instead of `fopen`. I provide an implementation of `getline` using a file descriptor instead of a `FILE*`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

struct node {
    char *data;
    struct node *next;
};

// getlinefd reads a full line from fd into *lineptr. Initialize *lineptr to NULL and *n to 0.
// getlinefd will store the line into *lineptr which is is a buffer that will grow as needed.
// The buffer size is stored in *n. The line ends '\0' and with a '\n'when present.
// getlinefd returns the number of characters read, or -1 in case of error or if the end of file is reached.
ssize_t getlinefd(char **lineptr, size_t *n, int fd) {
    static char buf[256];
    static size_t len = 0;
    const size_t blen = sizeof(buf);

    if (lineptr == NULL || n == NULL) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }
    if (*lineptr == NULL)
        len = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (buf[i] == '\n') {
            i++;
            if (i+1 > *n)
                *lineptr = realloc(*lineptr, *n = i+1);
            strncpy(*lineptr, buf, i);
            (*lineptr)[i] = '\0';
            len -= i;
            memmove(buf, buf+i, len);
            return i;
        }
    }
    size_t l = 0;
    while (1) {
        ssize_t r = read(fd, buf+len, blen-len);
        if (r < 0)
            return -1;
        len += r;
        if (len == 0) {
            if (*lineptr != NULL)
                (*lineptr)[l] = '\0';
            return l ? l : -1;
        }
        for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (buf[i] == '\n') {
                i++;
                if (l+i+1 > *n)
                    *lineptr = realloc(*lineptr, *n = l+i+1);
                strncpy(*lineptr+l, buf, i);
                l += i;
                (*lineptr)[l] = '\0';
                len -= i;
                memmove(buf, buf+i, len);
                return l;
            }
        }
        if (l+len+1 > *n)
            *lineptr = realloc(*lineptr, *n = l+len+1);
        strncpy(*lineptr+l, buf, len);
        l += len;
        len = 0;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("expected the file name as command line argument\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("file name: %s\n", argv[1]);    

    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY, 0644);
    if (fd < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    // list of token is intially empty 
    struct node *head = NULL, *last = NULL;

    printf("\nREAD FROM FILE.\n");

    size_t bufLen = 0;
    char *line = NULL;
    // read a line from the file
    while(getlinefd(&line, &bufLen, fd) != -1)
    {
        // remove the trailing \n
        size_t len = strlen(line);
        if (len > 0 && line[len-1] == '\n')
            line[len-1] = '\0';

        // for each token in the line
        for (char *token = strtok(line, ","); token != NULL; token = strtok(NULL, ",")) {
            // append token to list
            struct node *q = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            q->data = strdup(token);
            q->next = NULL;
            if (last == NULL)
                head = last = q;
            else
                last = last->next = q;
        }
    }

    for (struct node *p = head; p != NULL; p = p->next)
        printf("%s\n", p->data);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes I have to pass a flag of -I(insertionsort) or -q(quicksort) during compile time to sort the linked list of tokens but check first if the file has strings or integers. Thank you so much for your time but one thing I wanted to add is that I have to use the system call open() and read() in tokens from the file.

Comment: @Amir this means that you can't use `getline`. You have to provide your own implementation of `getline`. It's not easy but feasible. [here](https://dev.w3.org/libwww/Library/src/vms/getline.c) is the source code of get line. You use it is as inspiration. Some change would be required because you have to use `read` operation and can't use the `feof` function.

Comment: We can not use any f-functions. This is so cumbersome I think I am about to just give up on c because I can not seem to get it. if I can not use any f functions that start with [ f ] then how else I am going to this whole project. We are working with all system calls and yet he gives us no resource that helps with this. And when I looked at your get line function. I am so confused of how to even go about it because I grew up coding JAVA and not c.

Comment: Why is that every time I try to look for how to use read operations and all I get is the other operation of fget. Seriously, is there anything that can help me ? or any information on system calls? And why there is no book ? I am so frustrated with this project, honestly. For once GOOGLE is so useless

Comment: @Amir you have [here](http://manpagesfr.free.fr/man/man2/read.2.html) the manual of the `read` function. You should be able to implement the `getline` function using the `read` function. I can look into it tomorrow.

Comment: That link you sent me is all in Spanish.

Comment: @Amir sorry, the page is in french. [Here](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read) is a man page in english.

Comment: @Amir I updated the code by providing a `getlinefd` funtion that reads a line using an fd instead of a `FILE*`. The interface of `getlinefd` is exactly the same as `getline`. The source code of `getline` that I gave as reference in a previous comment is invalid.

Comment: Wow your implementation is really great and so I will say that you are really appreciated for the work you put in. Thank you so much. I will study your implementation thoroughly and will put a use to it for my project and how you created the linked list will help me in the future.

Comment: I think there is a bug in your code because the tokens were not correct coming from the file. Characters were missing

Comment: @Amir there was indeed a mistake in the `getlinefd` code, but this bug would have added garbage characters. I don't see how we could have missing characters.  I fixed it and did a small optimization of the code. Unfortunately, I'm currently not able to test it. Could you verify that at least `getlinefd` is correct ? If not, I would need to know the size of `buf` you use and the average length of the lines in the file. Are the character missing in the tokens ? I didn't check that part. I'll do some tests later today. You can already try the fixed code.

Comment: @Amir I checked the code. The code in the answer was missing the include of errno.h. I added it. I changed the initialization of bufLen and line to 0 and NULL respectively. There is no error in `getlinefd`. No missing characters. I do get the tokens as expected.

Comment: My apology I was busy and did not come back here in time. I have done this same thing in a different way and it worked just fine the way I wanted. Im going to go ahead and play with your code and study how the professionals do it. Thank you for your time and support. I really appreciate it